# Copy and replace system file and open iso in WinArchiver(iso mounter) using bat file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command-prompt

I want to create a batch file to copy and replace system file and open an iso in WinArchiver (iso mounter).

This command is not working for copying:

```
COPY  RosettaStoneVersion3.exe  C:\Program Files\Rosetta Stone\Rosetta Stone Version 3\RosettaStoneVersion3.exe /y
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to `"quote"` any path or filename which contains spaces.

Comment: how to mount on winarchiver and how to replace system file